# How to deal with a mix of unicode- and non-unicode projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, character-encoding, mfc

Preamble: I know that 'Unicode' as the term is used by Microsoft is non-congruent with the term 'Unicode' outside of the Microsoft world. When I use 'Unicode' in the following, I mean 'UCS2 as it used in Windows' and in the context of Visual Studio build settings.

With that out of the way: with the upcoming Visual Studio 2013, Microsoft is finally phasing out MBCS builds. Which is what is spurring me to fix up our code base to enter the 21st century, and switch to Unicode builds for all our code that uses win32 and MFC. However, we use some external libraries that are portable, don't use anything Windows-specific and that use MBCS settings. I'm not looking forward to identifying each and every interaction point between those libraries and our own code, and deal with WideCharToMultiByte(), ATL conversion macros and consorts everywhere.

So my question is: what are the best practices on dealing with mixed mbcs/Unicode builds? Are there any guide documents or example applications where it's done?

I'm hoping there is a better way than having to define my own string type with conversion operators for all types that are used in the various libraries :)

Comment: `std::string` is always `std::string`. Are you sure you aren't thinking of `tstring`?

Comment: Yes that was a wrong example, I removed it.

Comment: Depending on how good you were in writing the code, it will be a nightmare... Truly :-) If everyone was very good and only used `tstring`, `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, `LPCTSTR`, `malloc(x * sizeof(TCHAR))` (note the `* sizeof(TCHAR)`) then it will only be half a nightmare :-) Then in two/three years it's rinse-and-repeat with 32->64 bits! :-) :-)

Comment: Windows does **not** equate UNICODE and UCS-2. Windows uses UTF-16 and its UNICODE support allows for surrogate pairs, which constitute 32-bit encodings of supplementary characters (see [Unicode (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081.aspx)).

Comment: For your consideration: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16, not UCS2.

Comment: @MihaiNita The complete sentence should be "newer Windows use UTF-16, not UCS2"... By reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/05/11/416552.aspx it seems around Xp, with some Uniscribe support in Windows 2000.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Was kind of implied that Win 95/98/Me are not there :-)

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like you own those libraries.

I would change them to use "Using Generic-Text Mappings" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dzey6h6.aspx
That way you can compiled them with UNICODE and _UNICODE defined for Windows, and without that on other systems.

You will have to write something like your own tchar.h though
(but pretty trivial, just a bunch of ifdefs to map _tprintf to wprintf/printf, for instance).